# MYSQL: Best way to export/import data to prevent consistency of tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database on two different server.

Database `"store" on server A` and same database `"store" on server B`

"store" database has following two tables:

```
+-----------------------+           +---------------------+
:      jobs             :           :      votes          :
+.......................+           +---------------------+
:job_id     :primary key: --------> : job_id : primary key: (Linked to jobs->job_id)
+-----------+...........+           +---------------------+
:     title             :           :      up             :
+-----------------------+           +---------------------+
:   description         :           :      down           :
+-----------------------+           +---------------------+
```

Table jobs and votes are related(linked) by `foreign key`.

**Database "store" at server A**

table `jobs` has 2300 rows, whose `job_id(primary key)` start from 1 to 2300

table `votes` has corresponding rows

**Database "store" at server B**

table `jobs` has 1200 rows, whose `job_id(primary key)` start from 1 to 1200

table `votes` has corresponding rows

**Problem:**

I want to import data `for server "A" database to server "B"` in such a way so that the rows(records) of server `A's` database table get inserted into server `B's` database table with the increment of `B's` table `"jobs" job_id` from 1200 onward.
And corresponding insert into `B's` table `votes` with new `job_id` of B's server jobs job_id .

**What are the possible secure ways to accomplice such importing of data?**

I can simply `export SQL from phpMyAdim from server A` and then `import to server B's phpMyAdmin`. But i am afraid to lost the consistency of the records.

Comment: Make a backup. Test operations on backup copies. If everything is fine, then do same on production.

Comment: So, you want to add items from Server A to server B, but you don't necessarily care about the autoincrement values (other than the items from A need to be have autoincrement values above those in DB B such that there are no id collisions)? And of course you need to maintain the relations of the items being brought over?

Comment: @Mike Brant The items from server A get inserted into B with new Id assigned by B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few potential approaches.  Which you use may depend on whether this is a one time thing or something you plan to do multiple times.

A very simple approach would be to add, say 10000 to all the autoincrement values in both tables in DB A and then just create and SQL script that can import these values into the DB B.  You would have a gap in the autoincrement sequence, but this should really be a problem.  (You could obviously modify this approach to add the exact number of rows for each table in DB B to the autoincrement values in DB A tables if you wanted to prevent such a gap).

Another approach might be to write up a script to do this migration for you.  With this approach, you could read the data from DB A and making inserts across joins in DB B to enforce the relationships, while letting DB B set autoincrement values automatically.

Yet another approach might be to import the data from DB A into separate tables in DB B, then select the data from the new tables and insert into existing tables across a join.

Comment: it sound good, thanks for replay- waiting for more other experts suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider looking into UUIDs.  Using this approach, your key will be a unique key across all servers.  This is a little more work to be done on the front side to make this approach work, but once you are using it, combining databases is not a problem.

[Get the generated uuid after insert php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933296/get-the-generated-uuid-after-insert-php)

Comment: so you are saying to take help of PHP or other script, to insert data from A to B

Comment: Actually, I am saying that if you design your database to use UUIDs, combining two databases is a trivial amount of work.