# Retrieving last inserted ID for InnoDB composite key table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, auto-increment

I have the following table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `my_table` (
  composite_pk1 INT NOT NULL ,
  composite_pk2 INT NOT NULL ,
  data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   primary key (composite_pk1, composite_pk2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

For a given `composite_pk1`, I wish `composite_pk2` to act as an autoincrement primary key.  I don't wish to lock the table, and as such plan on using a trigger such as the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.composite_pk2 = (
       SELECT IFNULL(MAX(composite_pk2), 0) + 1
       FROM issue_log
       WHERE composite_pk1  = NEW.composite_pk1
 );

END $$
```

I can now insert a record:

```
$stmt=$myDB->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table(composite_pk1, data) VALUES (?,?)');
$stmt->execute([123,'hello']);
```

How do I get the last inserted `composite_pk2`?  `PDO::lastInsertId` only works with native autoincrement tables (i.e. not the trigger approach).  I "could" later do a SELECT query to get the max value, however, there is no guarantee that another record has snuck in.

Comment: There really isn't a good way to do this, unfortunately.  The other issue you may face is the case where the MAX function returns a value that another update/insert statement has just used due to read consistency.  You can have contention for that number.  Is the order of that composite_pk2 important?

Comment: @TGray Will not the trigger ensure no update/inserts snuck in?  What do you mean regarding "read consistency"?  In regards to order of the `composite_pk2` being important, what do you mean?  Thanks

Comment: 1 - no, the trigger doesn't lock a value, which means that someone working on a completely different record could also have retrieved the max(value) while you were working.  2 - Read consistency means "I work on a copy of the data while someone else works on a copy - if something changes while I"m looking at it, I don't know until my trigger fails (for example)".  3 - Does the composite_pk2 have to be ordered - 1, 2, 3, 4, ...?  If not, you might consider using uuid() instead of a function defined numeric.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933296/get-the-generated-uuid-after-insert-php

Comment: @TGray  Ah, thanks for #1 and #2.  In regards to #3, order will be nice but is not required, and was considering a uuid if necessary (don't like the extra weight, however).  Is `uuid()` typically used to first generate and return the key, and then inserted in a separate query?  If not, how is it returned to the application?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `composite_pk2` an unique key with `auto_increment`:

```
CREATE  TABLE `my_table` (
  composite_pk1 INT NOT NULL ,
  composite_pk2 INT NOT NULL unique auto_increment,
  data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   primary key (composite_pk1, composite_pk2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now `last_insert_id()` will return the recently created id for `composite_pk2`.

Comment: With InnoDB engine?

Comment: @user1032531, yes. according to the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), `last_insert_id()` returns the auto incremented id.

Comment: I swore I read you couldn't do so with InnoDB, but your solution appears to work.  Thank you!  What is the reason for the unique index on composite_pk2?

Comment: `last_insert_id()` will not increment individually for each `composite_pk1` with InnoDB.  I upvoted this answer when I thought it worked.

Comment: @user1032531, right. the id is unique to the table. since you were considering using uuid, I thought it would be acceptable