# How to get a generated UUID type using JDBC getGeneratedKeys?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, uuid

This is specific to MySQL and `UUID` type of id for which I am using `uuid()` function of MySQL itself. It's giving me not null `resultSet`, but `next()` value is always empty.

Following is the code:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO fixtures "
                        + "(id, whatever1, whatever2, whatever3, whatever4, "
                        ...
                        + "created_at) "
                        + "VALUES(UUID(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
.
.
.
preparedStatement.setDate(23, sqlDate);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet keysResultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
System.out.println(keysResultSet); // com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@6892b3b6
if(keysResultSet != null && keysResultSet.next()){
     System.out.println("Generated Emp Id: "+keysResultSet.getString("id"));
} else {
     System.out.println("No KEYS GENERATED");
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure (which is why I comment), but IIRC, MySQL Connector/J will only return the autoincrement value, if any. As you don't use one, nothing is returned.

Comment: Also, not sure the name match the column name, so I would take the first column instead (or check the metadata of the resultset)

Comment: Side note, given the class name in the comments, you are using a development version of MySQL Connector/J. You might want to stick to released versions (latest is 5.1.45).

Comment: There is no key/auto increment value available.  Check your database and driver versions for best results.

Comment: Using the [`Statement.getGeneratedKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29), _"Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result"_ but there is no auto-generated keys since you specified the key yourself (using the function UUID)

Comment: @AxelH Some database drivers (eg PostgreSQL, Firebird), will return all columns.

Comment: From this [similar PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933296/get-the-generated-uuid-after-insert-php), I would say the solution proposed in quite good. (But this is not recent so might not be the case anymore). @MarkRotteveel, I don't like using the javadoc for SQL implementation... since every driver are different... but I took some liberty ;)

Comment: Not sure if it is supported by MySQL, but you could also try using `prepareStatement(insertQuery, new String[] { "id" })` to see if it then returns the actual column value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Have tried `prepareStatement(insertQuery, new String[] { "id" })` implementation too. But no gain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no key generated, but actually provided:

So either leave the creation to the database:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO fixtures "
                        + "(whatever1, whatever2, whatever3, whatever4, "
                        ...
                        + "created_at) "
                        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
                        + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

As I am not aware of how to easily achieve a UUID on the MySQL side, I would suggest the original solution with a UUID on java side:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO fixtures "
                        + "(id, whatever1, whatever2, whatever3, whatever4, "
                        ...
                        + "created_at) "
                        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
                        + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
 preparedStatement.setString(1, id.toString());
```

Getting the UUID then becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah. That's the work around I was planning to use if no solution is found. But just didn't want to leave dependency to my application-language for UUID generation when I already have function available in mysql.

Comment: And as per your comment *There is no key generated, but actually provided* - `String yourSQL="insert into Table1(Id,Col2,Col3) values(SEQ.nextval,?,?)";` also have id provided the same way I am doing. But that still returns resultSet.

Comment: If there are no (AUTOINCREMENT) keys generated, the ResultSet is empty. If `id` would have been an `INT AUTOINCR` and not provided by the INSERT, the ResultSet would be filled. I am not sure there is a way to cause a ResultSet with a UUID key. Till now, with for instance JPA all UUID keys I encountered were generated at the java side.

Comment: So SEQ.nextval (Oracle?) return a value in getGeneratedKeys?

Comment: Yeah. With JPA/Hibernate, we have annotation support, which itself makes most of the work done at the application side itself. So their Generator annotation helps that out. But I am trying to code for AWS Lambda, so just trying to make the microservice as light as I can. Hence went for pure JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 and later you can define a primary key using an auto-generated UUID.  To retrieve the UUID generated by the INSERT statement, add the OUTPUT option after your column definitions, and replace your statement.executeUpdate for statement.executeQuery and retrieve the value from the ResultSet. Here is a code fragment showing how to do it:

```
            sqlStmt.append("INSERT INTO tableName");
            sqlStmt.append(" (column1");
            sqlStmt.append(", column2");
...
            sqlStmt.append(" OUTPUT inserted.columnUUID");
            sqlStmt.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStmt.toString());
            statement.clearParameters();
            int index = 0;
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next())
            {
                result = resultSet.getString(1);
                companyDB.varUUID = result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jop Eggan's answer solves it. However, you can do the following too in case the approach gives any errors:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO fixtures "
                        + "(id, whatever1, whatever2, whatever3, whatever4, "
                        ...
                        + "created_at) "
                        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
                        + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
 preparedStatement.setObject(1, id);
```